# How to use RandomTrue if condition is met in Anylogic Transition element?

Tags: anylogic

[image]

I am working on a model, where the condition is if the agent has money>10.0. If true then 50% agent should go forward to the next state.

I also tried this as in image below

[image]

But I am not sure if it is right or wrong.

How can I model this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am working on a model, where the condition is if the agent has money>10.0. If true then 50% agent should go forward to the next state.

This is entirely wrong :) Agents do not pass through state charts ever. State charts define behavior of individual agents.

If you want what you say above, you need to use flow chart blocks and a `SelectOutput` element with the condition `agent.Money>50 && randomTrue(0.5)`